# Factory methods in JAXB accessing the element?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use a factory method instead of a no-args constructor for JAXB.

I have multiple classes that inherit from a base class, and the only indication as to which would be instantiated is an attribute `type` in the xml element.

```
<tag-name type="boolean"/>
```

would instantiate a BooleanType, whereas

```
<tag-name type="integer"/>
```

would instantiate an IntegerType.

Is there any way I can access the element name / attribute values of the element being unmarshalled from within the factory method?

(Is this, perhaps, a benefit of using a factory method over a no-args constructor? Are there others?)

(I am not using MOXy)

Answer (score 3):

> I have multiple classes that inherit from a base class, and the only
>   indication as to which would be instantiated is an attribute type in
>   the xml element.

Using any [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation you could use an `XmlAdapter` to map an inheritance relationship where an arbitrary XML attribute is the inheritance indicator.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

However instead of using an arbitrary XML attribute I would use the `xsi:type` attribute so that the contents could be properly validated by an XML schema.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

If you still wanted to use an arbitrary XML attribute and you were using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) are your JAXB provider then you could leverage the `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` extension:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

---

> Is there any way I can access the element name / attribute values of
>   the element being unmarshalled from within the factory method?

JAXB implementations do allow you to specify factory classes and methods via the `@XmlType` annotation, but I do not believe this is what you are looking for in this use case.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

To leverage the XML contents to determine the appropriate subclass to instantiate you would need to use the `XmlAdapter` approach.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know too much about Adapters yet, but I will definitely look into them. As an aside, I think every question I've seen related to JAXB had an answer by you. I was not surprised at all when you answered this one.